# How can i convert from wostream to ostream

Tags: c++, unicode, ostream

i am using a function that receives ostream but i have wostream is there a way to convert one to the other?

in particular i want to use boost::write_graphviz which takes ostream but i currently in << operator for wostream.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can convert. You will have to get an ostream.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd rather change my approach, rather than trying to convert `wostream` to `ostream`. I am sure that what you want to get can easily be achieved without wide char streams.

Of course, it depends on what is the actual purpose of your application, but in 9 of 10 cases simple implemention of your own converting routine or usage of third-party libraries (e.g. `iconv`) would obviously be enough.

**Update:** (as a proof of what I'm saying)
Google code has only one search result for `wofstream` and two - for `wifstream`. Doesn't that fact speak for itself?

Answer (score 0):

If the graph output does not have a wostream operator then you can do this:

```
std::wstring convert(std::string const& s)
{
  unsigned char const* tmp = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(s.data());

  std::wstring res = std::wstring(tmp, tmp + s.size());

  return res;
}

void f(std::wostream & out)
{
  std::ostringstream gout;
  gout << graph; // or whatever...
  out << convert(gout.str());
}
```

The cast is necessary if your string can have any value above 177.  If it can the turn into strange characters because the cast the wstring constructor will do turns negatives into negatives instead of straight bit copy.